# Directions of Interfacial Tensions

Tags: boundary-conditions, surface-tension

[image: C]

[source: Wikipedia/contact angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle)


Here there are 3 interfacial tensions acting on the water drop which is known to wet a surface. But I am unable to understand the reasoning for the direction of these tensions, I could think of reasoning but couldn't satisfy myself with it:
Interfacial tensions arise due to the adhesive forces and act in a way analogous to surface tension, so I  based my first(and the only reasoning that I could think of) reasoning about the fact that interfacial tensions would act to maintain minimal surface area in A-B interface. Let me discuss my thoughts for each interfacial tension:

### Solid-Liquid Interface

In the above image that has been attached, solid-liquid interfacial tension($\mathrm{\gamma_{SL}}$) is shown to act tangential to the surface which is understandable as these tension forces would try to establish minimal interfacial areal contact.

### Solid-Gas Interface

The direction of solid-gas interfacial tension($\mathrm{\gamma_{SG}}$) makes no sense to me at all.

### Liquid-Gas Interface

It took me a long time to understand the direction of Liquid-Gas interfacial tension($\mathrm{\gamma_{LG}}$) but even then, I only got the direction opposite to the one given in image. So, How did I get there? I reversed the image upside down in my head and remembered that Liquid-Gas Interface here tries to attain minimal surface energy. And I also remembered the dynamic situation of a needle floating over a water surface and compared it to that.
[image]

[source: Edu.Rsc](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fedu.rsc.org%2Fexperiments%2Fdetergents-soaps-and-surface-tension%2F1719.article&psig=AOvVaw0fxDTZkA1vyAFCbrsSXzJ0&ust=1622136305447000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAMQjB1qFwoTCMCquO7u5_ACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAK)
 which I can compare with the following:

[image] 
 [source: MS-Paint, My computer and me]
and would thus get the direction of tension opposite to the one mentioned.
To be Clear, I am repeating my question which is as follows:

> What is the reasoning for the directions for the interfacial tensions in the given image? And Is my reasoning for Solid-Liquid and Liquid-Gas Interface correct.?